# Convert a model trained in CUDNNLSTM so that the trained model can be run on CPU also

Tags: tensorflow, cudnn

I have a model trained in CUDNNLSTM, how can I use this in CPU? How can we export CUDNNLSTM variables to CPU bases weights so that the trained model can be run on CPU also.

Comment: When I freeze the model into a pb file and run using that I get this error: Not found: Op type not registered 'CudnnRNN' in binary running on <my device name>. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process

Answer (score 0):

One safe way, that always works, would be to simply save the variables to some file with appropriate format like hdf5 and manually load them again. This way you have complete control over what is happening and don't depend on the system you are using. You can even train a model in TensorFlow, save the variables and load them for use with a different library like PyTorch (assuming you defined the exact same model there).